# creating an SQL command in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I use direct SQL queries in rails and I am wanting to make SQL querys less verbose.

i am thinking of adding somthing along the lines of:

```
    $SQL = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

so i can use:

```
    $SQL.execute("<query>")
```

or:

```
    def SQL(params)
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(params)
    end
```

so i can use:

```
    SQL("<query>")
```

firstly:
Where would be the best place in a rails app to make this universally accessible?

secondly:
is there any reason this would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can put your code in a class and put the file inside your lib directory. After telling to rails to load that file you will be able to call your method wherever you want.
2. It's a bad idea because in this way you are not using ActiveRecord at all. ActiveRecord allows you to customize very deeply all SQL produced by it, but if you can't get what you desire I would suggest to use at least find_by_sql method which is available in your models.

For example, having a User model, you can do

```
User.find_by_sql("place here your sql query")
```

Doing so all retrieved records will be "mounted" in model instances and you will be able to use it in the same way as they would be fetched via a classic where(..) query.